# Use of singletons in compiler

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am writing a compiler for a C++-like language. I have to deal with symbol table which is represented in my code with class that has only static data and methods.

It's like:

```
class GlobalTable
{
    /* static members */
    static map<int, Symbol*> symbol_by_id;
    static map<Symbol*, int> id_by_symbol;

    /* some static methods */
};
```

Also is have a class which represents config:

```
class GlobalConfig
{
    static const int int_size;
    /* and so on ... */
};
```

I need to access these from a lot of places. Passing it around will result in swelling of code.
Is it convenient to use my class like that, or there is a better way to organize everything?

Comment: Passing what around? A Symbol* or GlobalTable ?

Comment: Passing around GlobalTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a compiler, usually you store a symbol type in a symbol table, for some definition of symbol. Generally, I have a symbol table per scope, so the global scope in each module or compilable unit has its own symbol table.

You'll also have AST nodes that have symbols and symbol subtpes as their members.

Most internal compiler apis deal with symbol and ast subtypes, and those are stored in a indexed, fast access data structure. All of this has to be available to most compiler functions, so you either use a global compiler or context variable, or pass one around as a paramter.

Strictly, there is no need to use singletons. I can only talk in examples, so the way I do it is with a Compiler class that has instance members like currentScope and globalScope as well as the root AST or currentCompilableUnit, so the parser main instantiates a Compiler, and everything is reentrant. It is a bit more convenient, though, if your compiler instance is a global variable, so your functions can omit the compiler parameter, but besides that, not really any need for any others.

In short, it is typical for most APIs to include a "scope" or "compiler" struct or class in many of its signatures. Though if you use OOP to model the compiler, any methods of the class have implicit "this" access.

Comment: I am able to compile code well, it works. My question is how to organize my code of compiler to make it more flexible. Can I somehow take care of global classes only with static members?

Comment: By global class do you mean globals in your compiler source code, or in your language?

Comment: Oh. No, there is no need to use singletons. I can only talk in examples, so the way I usually do it is to have a Compiler class that has regular members like currentScope and globalScope as well as the root AST or currentCompilableUnit, so the parser main instantiates a Compiler, and everything is reentrant. It makes it simpler, though, if your compiler instance is a global variable, so your functions can omit the compiler parameter, but besides that, not really any need for any others.

Comment: I understand that. I need a way to make GlobalTable visible to other classes. At the moment it is done using singleton. Are there another way?

Comment: My "GlobalTable" is an instance member variable in my Compiler class. Member functions of Compiler use this.globalScope, and external functions / classes use compiler.globalScope, but I described alternative in my revised answer.

Comment: I believe you have not only Compiler class but also other classes which process AST nodes. They also need to access globalTable, but it is member in Compiler. Do you pass reference to it?

Comment: In practicality, you rarely need more than one compiler obj, so global/singleton works for convenience. All I am saying is, it isnt required. Do you want your compiler to be reentrant? If so, pass references. Otherwise, Keep It Simple.

Comment: Mail me offline if you want to discuss in more detail, my email is in my profile. I can give you some sample code that is out of scope for this forum.